# Set up of Watson developer in unity: credentials

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, augmented-reality, speech-to-text, watson

I am trying to integrate Watson speech to text api in my unity project. But I am not able to configure the credentials(acess key) as the Watson Tap in the unity 2017.2 beta does not have "config editor" option. Is there any other way to configure credentials for Watson developer IBM?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H35Vo.png

Answer (score 0):

The Config Editor was deprecated since v1.0.0. You must now supply credentials when instantiating the service. For example:

```
void Start()
{
    Credentials credentials = new Credentials(<username>, <password>, <url>);
    Conversation _conversation = new Conversation(credentials);
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk#authentication) for more details.